# get number of rows in a fusiontable using google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-maps, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

I thought it should be quite simple getting the number of rows in a Google Fusiontable using their google-api-php-client library which can be found on Github https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and contains a service class Fusiontables.php. 
The service resource table has a function listTable() which followed by ->getItems() returns a list of all fusion tables as objects. Unfortunately these objects do not contain data about the number of rows, which would be quite handy.

So I tried the query resource with function sql()

```
$FusiontablesService->query->sql('SELECT COUNT() FROM '.$table->tableId);
```

and get this result

```
Google_Service_Fusiontables_Sqlresponse Object
(
  [collection_key:protected] => rows
  [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

  [columns] => Array
    (
        [0] => count()
    )

  [kind] => fusiontables#sqlresponse
  [rows] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

  [modelData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

  [processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

I know the table contains a huge amount of data. So why the query returns just 0?
Is there a better way to get the number of rows in a fusion table?

Comment: Why is this tagged [google-maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps)? Doesn't seem to have anything to do with maps.